# Need clarification with glGetProgramiv function

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

I am new to openGL environment.
Can someone tell me how are these functions different from one another?

1. **glGetProgramiv**
2. **glGetObjectParameteriv**
3. **glGetObjectParameterivARB**
4. **glGetObjectParameterivAPPLE**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real difference between those 4 functions.
The 2, 3 and 4 are part of the old ARB/APPLE extensions for shader programming, but now that GLSL has been moved to Core OpenGL. you should only use glGetProgramiv.

Hope it helps!

Comment: There's one slight difference, the old extension form of GLSL used the same function for shader objects and program objects. But in core GLSL, you have to use `glGetProgramiv (...)` to get something like the linker status from a linked GLSL program and `glGetShaderiv (...)` to get the compiler status from a compiled GLSL shader.